# How do i parse this special date and time to a DateTime?

Tags: c#, datetime

I have this string "Sun Oct 11 21:53:26 +0000 2015" which i would like to parse it using a DateTime method but it fails, what can i do ?

I tried replacing the "+0000" part with empty string ("") but still didn't work.

Edit: The error i'm getting is "Not a valid DateTime value"

Here's some code:

```
 string JSONStr = TwitterHelper.getInstance().GetReq_UserTimeline(tbScreenName.Text, 1);

 JArray jarr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(JSONStr);

 string a = jarr[0]["created_at"].ToString().Replace("+0000", "");

 currentTweetInfo.created_at = DateTime.Parse(a);
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For your particular string (assuming the time zone offset is ALWAYS `+0000`), the format string would be:

```
var s  = "Sun Oct 11 21:53:26 +0000 2015";

var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(s,"ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss +0000 yyyy",
                               CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Could you explain me what is this CultureInfo line is ? what does it tell the function ?

Comment: @user1803300 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: It is a requirement of the `ParseExact` function that indicates what culture-specific rules, spelling, etc. to use.  `InvariantCulture` is a special class that has well-defined rules that don't change (they just happen to be based on US rules and spellings)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ParseExact`:

```
string dateString, format;  
DateTime result;
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

// Parse date and time with custom specifier.
dateString = "Sun 15 Jun 2008 8:30 AM -06:00";
format = "ddd dd MMM yyyy h:mm tt zzz";
result = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, provider);
```

More information at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: it was just an example, the OP should configure the format according to his pattern.